# Black-Scholes option pricing

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes

Consider Black-Scholes (B, S) market model. Let $r = 0$ (hence, $B_t ≡ 1$), $S_0 = 0 $.
Stock price is described by $dS_t = σS_tdW_t$.
Find the price of the option that pays
$(S_T^3 - S_T^2 )_+ = max(S_T^3 - S_T^2, 0)$.

Any help on how exactly to apply Girsanov here?

Comment: Apparently it is different, because $S_t$ is a martingale, but $S_t^2$ is not.

Comment: yes, $S_t$ is a martingale but I don’t see why the standard approach wouldn’t work just because $r=0$.

Comment: I also think that the link provided by Kevin gives you the approach: 1) Split up the expectation using the indicator function. 2) Use the measure where $S_t^3$ is numeraire for the first part of the expectation. 3) Use the measure where $S_t^2$ is numeraire for the second part of the expectation.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)